# AngularJS directive error with templateUrl

Tags: angularjs-directive

Directive is not working in my application. I'm not sure what exactly I'm missing.

index.cshtml:

```
 <div>
        <test-directive> </test-directive>
    </div>
```

Directive.js:

```
   bingAdsDiagnostics.angular.loadApp.directive("testDirective", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: "/Home/Test"
        };
    });
```

If I use template (`template: '<div>vijay</div>'`)instead of templateUrl it is working good. templateUrl is not finding test.cshtml

Test.cshtml:

```
<h2>Test</h2>
```

Error:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/$compile/tpload?p0=%2FHome%2FTest
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

templateUrl needs to be the full path to the HTML file.  So something like:

```
templateUrl: "/Home/Test/test.cshtml"
```

Comment: test.cshtml is under Home folder. I don't have test folder. I've tried with templateUrl: "/Home/test.cshtml" also, but no luck

Comment: Are you seeing a 404 in the console?

Comment: Yes I'm seeing 404 :) in Fiddler.